# Intermittent Error using Google Maps API: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, typeerror

Hi All: a little help needed...

I am trying to use Google Maps API now and I followed all the instructions from the official google site for it. **However, I noticed that it doesn't always work.**

Often times, I get an error:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/8/main.js
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I sometimes refresh and it works. But sometimes this error appears in the console.
Is this an issue with the API or my code?

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SQ3Bx/

```
<script>var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(14.572388, 121.057784);
            var marker;
            var map;

            function initialize() {

                var styles = [
                    {
                        stylers: [
                            { hue: "#319885" },
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        featureType: 'water',
                        elementType: 'geometry.fill',  
                        stylers: [
                            { color: '#3191fe' }
                        ]
                    }
                ];

                var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
                    {name: "Timeframe Style"});

                var isDraggable = $(document).width() > 1000 ? true : false;

                var mapOptions = {
                    draggable: isDraggable,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    zoom: 14,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, 'map_style']
                    }
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                image = 'img/map_marker.png';
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: myLatlng,
                    icon: image
                });

                map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
                map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
            }

            function toggleBounce() {

                if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
                    marker.setAnimation(null);
                } else {
                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                }
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: How do you load google api and jquery?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

Comment: did you ever get this to work? please post the solution, or link to it.